# Getting 403 forbidden in cypress for a simple login hosted on akamai

Tags: cypress, akamai, cypress-component-test-runner

I am running this script to access a website hosted under akamai :

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />


 describe('Store login', () => {
  it('login to Store', () => {
    cy.visit(("https://store.qlsit.qantas.com/"),{
    headers: {
      "Accept" : "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
      "LOYALTY-PARTNER-FORWARD": "D19313AA-5BFF-4586-947A-C3AE8D78CEA4"
            }
        })
      })
     })
```

I am getting 403 forbidden .

I am not sure what header to add here to pass akamai blocker to access the website?

I have tried with different user-agent but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to login to the website ?

Comment: Juts trying to access it first. I need to login eventually though after this 403 error is resolved. @soccerway

Comment: Can you try this way: 
`options = {
  url: 'https://store.qlsit.qantas.com/',
  headers: {
     "Accept": 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
     "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
     "LOYALTY-PARTNER-FORWARD": 'D19313AA-5BFF-4586-947A-C3AE8D78CEA4'
    }
}
cy.visit(options);`

Comment: Please refer here: Just see if that helps ! https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4216

Answer (score 0):

As explained in previous commands, your issue seems to be related with the way you are calling `cy.visit` function. Url should be part of options, a separated argument is not well supported. Please try the following:

```js
 describe('Store login', () => {
  it('login to Store', () => {
    cy.visit({
    url: "https://store.qlsit.qantas.com/",
    headers: {
      "Accept" : "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
      "LOYALTY-PARTNER-FORWARD": "D19313AA-5BFF-4586-947A-C3AE8D78CEA4"
            }
        })
      })
     })
```

Make sure your version of cypress is recent enough and if the error persist, you may reach out to webmaster (or Akamai representative if you are customer) to get more information about that 403.